# Fabric and Crashlytics not working with Bazel build

Tags: android, crashlytics, bazel, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I'am building an android app which uses fabric-crashlytics for logging all the crashes in devices.
This particular line of code:

```
    Crashlytics crashlyticsKit = new Crashlytics.Builder()
            .core(new CrashlyticsCore.Builder().disabled(false).build())
            .build();
    Fabric.with(this, crashlyticsKit);
```

is crashing with Bazel, but, when I set this value to "true"..(i.e., I'am disabling Crashlytics ), this application's Bazel build is working fine.
But, If I'am building a normal android app it's not crashing weather the value is "true" or "false". But, in Bazel the build  is completely crashing on start.
The error is:

```
2019-01-11 15:55:55.808 19850-19850/com.sensennetworks.senanpr E/CrashlyticsCore: .
2019-01-11 15:55:55.808 19850-19850/com.sensennetworks.senanpr E/CrashlyticsCore: .     |  | 
2019-01-11 15:55:55.808 19850-19850/com.sensennetworks.senanpr E/CrashlyticsCore: .     |  |
2019-01-11 15:55:55.808 19850-19850/com.sensennetworks.senanpr E/CrashlyticsCore: .     |  |
2019-01-11 15:55:55.808 19850-19850/com.sensennetworks.senanpr E/CrashlyticsCore: .   \ |  | /
2019-01-11 15:55:55.808 19850-19850/com.sensennetworks.senanpr E/CrashlyticsCore: .    \    /
2019-01-11 15:55:55.808 19850-19850/com.sensennetworks.senanpr E/CrashlyticsCore: .     \  /
2019-01-11 15:55:55.808 19850-19850/com.sensennetworks.senanpr E/CrashlyticsCore: .      \/
2019-01-11 15:55:55.808 19850-19850/com.sensennetworks.senanpr E/CrashlyticsCore: .
2019-01-11 15:55:55.808 19850-19850/com.sensennetworks.senanpr E/CrashlyticsCore: This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
    install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.
2019-01-11 15:55:55.808 19850-19850/com.sensennetworks.senanpr E/CrashlyticsCore: .
2019-01-11 15:55:55.808 19850-19850/com.sensennetworks.senanpr E/CrashlyticsCore: .      /\
2019-01-11 15:55:55.808 19850-19850/com.sensennetworks.senanpr E/CrashlyticsCore: .     /  \
2019-01-11 15:55:55.808 19850-19850/com.sensennetworks.senanpr E/CrashlyticsCore: .    /    \
2019-01-11 15:55:55.808 19850-19850/com.sensennetworks.senanpr E/CrashlyticsCore: .   / |  | \
2019-01-11 15:55:55.808 19850-19850/com.sensennetworks.senanpr E/CrashlyticsCore: .     |  |
2019-01-11 15:55:55.808 19850-19850/com.sensennetworks.senanpr E/CrashlyticsCore: .     |  |
2019-01-11 15:55:55.808 19850-19850/com.sensennetworks.senanpr E/CrashlyticsCore: .
2019-01-11 15:55:55.812 19850-19850/com.sensennetworks.senanpr E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

How do I properly integrate fabric and crashlytics for them to work in Bazel?

My dependencies in BUILD file are:

```
 deps = [
        ":tensorflow_native_libs",
        "//tensorflow/contrib/lite/java:tensorflowlite",
        "@com_google_code_gson_gson//jar",
        "@com_mcxiaoke_volley_library//jar",
        #"@com_sun_mail_android_activation//jar",
        #"@com_sun_mail_android_mail//jar",
        gmaven_artifact("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:aar:15.0.1"),
        gmaven_artifact("com.android.support:appcompat-v7:aar:26.1.0"),
        gmaven_artifact("com.android.support:design:aar:26.1.0"),
        gmaven_artifact("com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:aar:26.1.0"),
        gmaven_artifact("com.android.support:support-v4:aar:26.1.0"),
        gmaven_artifact("io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:aar:1.3.17"),
        gmaven_artifact("com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:aar:2.9.0"),
        #gmaven_artifact("com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-core:aar:2.6.4"),
        gmaven_artifact("com.google.firebase:firebase-core:aar:15.0.2")]
```

Comment: Filed a bug: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/7159

Comment: Crashlytics integration is currently not supported in Bazel yet, because it depends on some manipulation of your build from the io.fabric Gradle plugin. Bazel does not invoke that plugin, so the app crashes at runtime due to some missing files. We're currently working on making this work with Bazel, please follow along the issue for more information.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement Fabric Crashlytics in Android with Bazel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54237225/how-to-implement-fabric-crashlytics-in-android-with-bazel)

Answer (score 1):

You can now integrate Crashlytics directly into your Bazel build with `crashlytics_android_library` using [`bazelbuild/tools_android`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/tools_android).

```
load("@rules_maven//:defs.bzl", "artifact")
load("@tools_android//tools/crashlytics:defs.bzl", "crashlytics_android_library")
load("@tools_android//tools/googleservices:defs.bzl", "google_services_xml")

GOOGLE_SERVICES_RESOURCES = google_services_xml(
    package_name = "com.example.package",
    google_services_json = "google-services.json",
)

crashlytics_android_library(
    name = "crashlytics_lib",
    package_name = "com.example.package",
    build_id = "9dfea8fe-4d75-48a7-ba28-4ddb7fe74780",
    resource_files = GOOGLE_SERVICES_RESOURCES,
)

android_library(
    name = "crashlytics_deps",
    exports = [
        artifact("com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics"),
        artifact("io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric"),
    ],
)

android_library(
    name = "my_release_lib",
    srcs = glob(["src/main/**/*.java"]),
    manifest = "AndroidManifest.xml",
    resource_files = glob(["res/**/*"]),
    deps = [
        ":crashlytics_lib",
        ":crashlytics_deps", 
    ],
)
```

For more information, read https://github.com/bazelbuild/tools_android/blob/master/tools/crashlytics/README.md